# Count how many times a static method is called in Spock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am trying to count how many times static methods are called.

I want to verify the counts of the base and inner method calls.

Shown below is a very simplified code.  I have tried a few variations but cannot run without error.

I am trying to verify the counts of:

- `ClassX.CallsClassY()`
- `ClassY.DoSomething()`

Please help.

Error Message:

```
Too few invocations for:

interactions * globalMock.DoSomething()   // Does not work   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

2 * globalMock.DoSomething()  
2 * globalMock.println('Hello Spock')

    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionScope.verifyInteractions(InteractionScope.java:78)  
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.leaveScope(MockController.java:76)  
    at SpockSpec.Count how many times ClassY is called(SpockSpec.groovy:10)
```

Code:

```java
    import spock.lang.Specification

    class SpockSpec extends Specification {
        def "Count how many times ClassY is called"(){
        def count = 5
        def interactions = count + 1
        def globalMock = GroovySpy(ClassY, global: true)

        when:
        ClassX.CallClassY(count)

        then:
        count == 5
        // TODO:  Count how many times ClassY.DoSomething() and ClassX.CallClassY() is called
        interactions * globalMock.DoSomething()   // Does not work
    }

    class ClassX {

        public static void CallClassY(int count)
        {
            count.times {
                ClassY.DoSomething()
            }

            ClassY.DoSomething()
        }
    }

    class ClassY {
        static void DoSomething() {
            println "Hello Spock"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only *global* mocks can mock static methods. For details see the reference documentation (http://docs.spockframework.org).

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Thanks for the suggestion.  I updated the code and tried using GroovySpy as defined in "[Mocking Static Methods](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#mocking-static-methods)" section, but I still get an error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One thing that's wrong is that the mocked method has no arguments, but `_` means "any single argument".

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I had tried with no argument as well and got similar error.  But I will update the code and error message.

Comment: The correct syntax for mocking static methods is `interactions * ClassY.DoSomething()`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Thanks.  I knew I was doing something stupid.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
def "Count how many times ClassB is called"(){
        given:
            def calls = 0
        and:
            ClassY.metaClass.'static'.DoSomething = {
                calls++
            }
        and:
            def count = 5        
        when:
            ClassX.CallClassY(count)
        then:
            count == calls + 1
    }
```